# OpenSSL certificate error

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate

I am writing a program with OpenSSL library, to establish a SSL POP connection 
with other server (E.g. Gmail). For this, I have generated a self signed certificate 
using OpenSSL and verified it.

```
./openssl verify -CAfile /home/melluru/openssl/ssl/certs/cert.pem
           /home/melluru/openssl/ssl/certs/cert.pem
>/home/melluru/openssl/ssl/certs/cert.pem: OK
```

The verify option of OpenSSL tools gives 'OK' result. But when I use the below in 
my program to load the certtificate and verify the result, I am getting the error

```c
/** to add the cert file**/  
if(!(SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(ctx,"/home/melluru/openssl/ssl/certs/cert.pem",
                             SSL_FILETYPE_PEM)))
    printf("Cant read certificate file\n");
/** to add the private key ***/
if(!(SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(ctx,"/home/melluru/openssl/ssl/certs/cert.pem",
                           SSL_FILETYPE_PEM)))
    printf("Cant read keyfile\n");
/** to cadd the trusted cert **/   
if(SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(ctx,"/home/melluru/openssl/ssl/certs/cert.pem",
                             NULL) != 1) {
    printf("loading trust certificate failed\n");
    SSL_CTX_free(ctx);
    return 0;
}

/*** BIO code to connect to gmail server *****/

printf("ssl verify error is %d\n",SSL_get_verify_result(ssl));
```

I am getting error 20 `X509_V_ERR_UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY`.
Can anyone help? Is there anything still I need to add?

Answer (score 2):

Since your certificate is self signed, you can use it to check its signature, like you did by using `openssl verify`command line.

However, when you try to establish an SSL connection, what you want to verify is not your certificate, but the certificate you are receiving from the server (or client).

In the line `SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations` you have to point to the certificate chain which you'll trust. It is this chain that will be checked against the certificate you are receiving trough the handshake protocol.

I've never worked with an environment like the one you are describing, but you are saying you want to connect to gmail, so it must be gmail's certificate chain in the line `SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations`

That's why you are receiving the error "X509_V_ERR_UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY". OpenSSL could not find the issuer cert locally (in the chain you've put trough the method `SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations`) of the certificate you are receiving.